# Defining modules in one file and requiring it in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm updating my code to include new packages so often and I have more than 100 files.

I want to make something like this,

File : dependencies.js :

```
const snekfetch = require("snekfetch");
const fs = require("fs");
```

It's very annoying to modify every file to add just a single package.

I'm trying to require the dependencies.js using this:

```
require("./dependencies.js")
```

But I see this in my console:

```
ReferenceError: snekfetch is not defined
```

Is there any way I can succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not exporting the modules in dependencies.js 
dependencies.js should look like,

```
    const snekfetch = require("snekfetch");
    const fs = require("fs");
    module.exports = {
      "snekfetch": snekfetch,
      "fs": fs
    };
```

Then you should be able to import this file and use it like as follows,

```
    var dependencies = require('./dependencies.js');
    // dependencies.fs.readFile();
```

Although there are much better ways to handle your imports then just creating a simple file of dependencies. Have a look at [this link](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and will inform you.

Comment: This didn't actually solve my thing but I got to the end myself. Thanks though.